# Is it possible to set the "message To:" header when sending email in PHP?

Tags: php, email

This is a relatively simple question that may just not have a solution.

Is it possible to set the **message To:** header and send the email in PHP? Note that **message To:** is different from the **envelope To:** header. The latter actually determines where the email is routed, and the former just determines what it shown in the recipient's email program.

Background: I'm setting up a little disposable email service for myself, so I'm receiving emails with a PHP script, modifying a few headers, and re-sending it to my real email address. I'd like the original recipient email address (the disposable email address) to still show up on the message when I receive it in my real email box (for client-side filtering rules, etc.).

Is this possible? I've been able to modify every other type of header, but this one has me stuck.

Comment: I looked and I can't find any "message to" header anywhere. Do you have a link to some sort of documentation?

Comment: @Mike - I suppose [this would help](http://www.owlriver.com/spam/stop-spam.html). The section titled "Envelope Headers" gets at what I'm talking about, i.e. envelope headers vs. message headers.

Comment: I think you're looking for the **To** header, not **message To**. Note the article you linked to says _"To: The "message To: "described above. Note that the To: header need not contain the recipient's address!"_

Comment: To: "displayed name" <email address>

Comment: Hmm... so it appears I've misunderstood the phrasing of the header. It apparently is just known as the "To:" header. The problem, however, is that PHP's mail() function interprets the "To:" header as the intended recipient and sends the email to that address. What I'm trying to do is send it to one address and have it appear as though it's meant for another (because it originally was, I'm essentially just forwarding it).

Comment: STMP is another option other than PHP, which ads more header control, if you'd like I could post the function I use for it.

Comment: @AlexLunix - Sure, I'm open to any solution.

Comment: Are you looking for the Bcc header? This way you can send a message To someone, and have another person get a copy of the message, giving the effect you're looking for. Email needs a To: header and the message will be delivered to that address, you can't address a message to someone and not have it delivered to that recipient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's help! I found an excellent solution, so I thought I'd share.

I ended up just extending CodeIgniter's email class to set a **To** header (I'm heretofore going to start calling it a vanity header since it's all looks and no substance) and sending via SMTP. If you want to see a simple example of what I did, extend the Email class with your own MY_Email.php file (see the section on [Extending Native Libraries](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html) in the User Guide) and copy over the _build_headers() function from the Email class.

```
    /**
 * Build final headers
 *
 * @access  protected
 * @param   string
 * @return  string
 */
protected function _build_headers()
{
    $this->_set_header('X-Sender', $this->clean_email($this->_headers['From']));
    $this->_set_header('X-Mailer', $this->useragent);
    $this->_set_header('X-Priority', $this->_priorities[$this->priority - 1]);
    $this->_set_header('Message-ID', $this->_get_message_id());
    $this->_set_header('Mime-Version', '1.0');
}
```

Then add your own header on the line immediately below the Mime-Version line, like so:

```
    $this->_set_header('To', 'person@example.com');
```

Then just send a regular email to one of your own email addresses. You'll notice that even though the email arrives at your address, it appears to be addressed to person@example.com.

Boom.

If you'd like to actually use the full MY_Email.php file I created to add a "Vanity To" option to your own CodeIgniter project, [see this gist](https://gist.github.com/1861286).

Answer (score 0):

Here I use something like this:

```
$message = 'Your Message';
$subject = 'Your Subject';
$headers = 'Your headers';
$to = 'Address to send to';
$headers = 'Reply-To: Address'; //Perhaps you are looking for this?

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Hope this works for you!

EDIT: Sorry misunderstood your problem.

Comment: Right, but the $to in that function sets the "envelope to" header, which determines the routing of the message, i.e. to which address it's sent. I've got that all set. What I'm trying to do now is modify the "message to" header, i.e. the address that is displayed in the recipient's mail program's "To:" field. Admittedly, most people have no idea there's a difference between the two headers.

Answer (score 0):

When sending emails with PHP I've always used a custom function that uses STMP, and in that function it uses the following header to set the name I believe your trying to set:

```
"To: $nameto <$emailto>"
```

Where $emailto is the actual email you're sending to, and $nameto is who you would like it to display it is for.

Here is the function I use, if you need to change any of the other headers you can modify them, they are towards the end of the function:

```
/*
    Desc: Used to send emails from stmp server. Make sure to have the config variables set (at the top of function). Stores logs in array, you'll need to modify the function to actually use the array though.
    Params:
        String $from - Email address that the email is from. Ex. "john.smith@example.com"
        String $namefrom - Name to go along with the email address. Ex. "John Smith"
        String $to - Email address of the recipient of the email. Ex, "jane.doe@example.com"
        String $nameto - Name to go along with the email address. Ex. "Jane Doe"
        String $subject - Email subject.
        String $message - Main contents of email.
    Return: true on success false on failure.
*/
function amail($from, $namefrom, $to, $nameto, $subject, $message)
{
    $smtpServer = "";
    $port = 0;
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $timeout = 30;
    $localhost = "127.0.0.1";
    $newLine = "\r\n";
    $smtpConnect = fsockopen($smtpServer, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout) or die('Could not connect.');
    $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
    if(empty($smtpConnect)){
        return false;
    } else {
        $logArray['connection'] = "Connected: $smtpResponse";
    }
    fputs($smtpConnect, "HELO $localhost" . $newLine);
    $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
    $logArray['heloresponse'] = "$smtpResponse";
    fputs($smtpConnect,"AUTH LOGIN" . $newLine);
    $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
    $logArray['authrequest'] = "$smtpResponse";
    fputs($smtpConnect, base64_encode($username) . $newLine);
    $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
    $logArray['authusername'] = "$smtpResponse";
    fputs($smtpConnect, base64_encode($password) . $newLine);
    $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
    $logArray['authpassword'] = "$smtpResponse";
    fputs($smtpConnect, "MAIL FROM: $from" . $newLine);
    $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
    $logArray['mailfromresponse'] = "$smtpResponse";
    fputs($smtpConnect, "RCPT TO: $to" . $newLine);
    $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
    $logArray['mailtoresponse'] = "$smtpResponse";
    fputs($smtpConnect, "DATA" . $newLine);
    $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
    $logArray['data1response'] = "$smtpResponse";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $newLine;
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1" . $newLine;
    $headers .= "To: $nameto <$to>" . $newLine;
    $headers .= "From: $namefrom <$from>" . $newLine;
    $headers .= "Subject: $subject" . $newLine;
    fputs($smtpConnect, "$headers\n\n$message\n".$newLine.".".$newLine);
    $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 1024);
    $logArray['data2response'] = "$smtpResponse";
    fputs($smtpConnect,"QUIT" . $newLine);
    $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
    $logArray['quitresponse'] = "$smtpResponse";
    return true;
}
```